# Having an issue opening a project

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I have a problem in Eclipse to open projects which are not in the list. for example, I found a new sample project in the Internet and downloaded it on my computer. Now, I want to open it in Eclipse but "Project>Open Project" menu does not work. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File -> New -> Project (Android Project). Then you need select "Create project at existing location (from existing sources)" and write appropriate directory in Directory field and thats all

Answer (score 1):

Try to create new android project with "from existing sources" option.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. File -> Import -> Existing projects into workspace
2. Select the project on the file
   system.
3. Click finish

Eclipse will import it into your workspace and open it for you.
Note that the physical location of the files does not change.